# Unity2D. Функция выхода из коллайдера

Tags: c#, unity3d

Имеется круг, в котором находится управляемый объект (назовем это ***хомяком в колесе***). По нажатию клавиши *хомяк* должен выпрыгнуть из *колеса*, чтобы перемещаться свободно без него.
Мне нужно, чтобы *хомяк* вышел коллайдера *колеса* по нажатию клавиши и толкнуть его вверх.

Я пытался отключать коллайдер на время у хомяка и колеса, но это не заканчивалось успехом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае я бы посоветовал сделать этот момент через анимацию Unity. При некотором условии Хомяк выходит из области колёса и делает, что захотите. А по окончанию анимации(можно поставить в конце анимации запуск метода) игрок получает контроль

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду Root анимацию, которая будет контролировать позицию хомяка в пространстве? А как в таком случае собрать толчок вверх?

Comment: Стандартное создание анимации в Unity вам в помощь, я это имел ввиду)